# Is there a quick way to see the fields in a table via arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I frequently find myself in Python debug mode, trying to examine the fields of a layer or table.

`arcpy.Describe(lyr).fields` returns an array of `<geoprocessing describe field object>` which isn't much use.

About 10 times a day I find myself typing this:

`flds = []
for fld in arcpy.Describe(lyr).fields:
    flds.append(fld.name)`

Is there a faster way to obtain a readable listing of the layer or table's fields in arcpy?

Comment: all I can think of is ListFields: for f in arcpy.ListFields(lyr): print f.name, but basically that's the same... you could compact that down to one line, in the end it's all the same. Even in ArcObjects you get a fields object from a feature class then iterate through it for (x=0;x<fields.count;x++) { ...}

Comment: A bit better - at least I can keep that in Notepad and paste it rather than typing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing works just fine.  This is pretty much the same code but as a more elegant solution:

```
flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(lyr)]
```

Comment: simplify it further: print [f.name...... ] , then save your common 'stuff' in a text file that you keep open when using ArcMap... now if only you could get rid of 'lyr' as something to change

Comment: yes, everyone should spend some time with python list comprehension.  it's super powerful and will help in all kinds of unexpected ways. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions